# Check if a list is in a custom order

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-3.6

I am trying to validate a list say:

`X = ['a','c', 'c', 'b', 'd','d','d']`

against a custom ordered list:

`Y = ['a',b','d']`

In this case X validated against Y should return `True` regardless of the extra elements and duplicates in it as long as it goes with the order in `Y` and contains at least two elements.

Case Examples:

```
X = ['a','b'] # Returns True
X = ['d','a', 'a', 'c','b'] # Returns False
X = ['c','a','b', 'b', 'c'] # Returns True
```

The most I can do right now is remove the duplicates and extra elements. I am not trying to sort them using the custom list. I just need to validate the order. What I done or at least tried is to create a dictionary where the value is the index of the order. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest, groupby

okay = list(x == y for y, (x, _) in zip_longest(
        (y for y in Y if y in X), groupby(x for x in X if x in Y)))
print(len(okay) >= 2 and all(okay))
```

First we discard unnecessary elements from both lists. Then we can use `groupby` to collapse sequences of the same elements of `X`. For example, your first example `['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd']` first becomes `['a', 'c', 'c', 'b'] (by discarding the unnecessary`'d'`), then`[('a', _), ('c', _), ('b', _)]. If we compare its keys element by element to the `Y` without the unnecessary bits, and there are at least 2 of them, we have a match. If the order was violated (e.g. `['b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd']`, there would have been a `False` in `okay`, and it would fail. If an extra element appeared somewhere, there would be a comparison with `None` (thanks to `zip_longest`), and again a `False` would have been in `okay`.

This can be improved by use of sets to speed up the membership lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list from X that only contains the elements from Y without duplicates. Then, similarly, remove all elements from Y not contained in X and deduplicate. Then your check is just a simple equality check.

```
def deduplicate(iterable):
    seen = set()
    return [seen.add(x) or x for x in iterable if x not in seen]

def goes_with_order(X, Y):
    Xs = set(X); Ys = set(Y)
    X = deduplicate(x for x in X if x in Ys)
    Y = deduplicate(y for y in Y if y in Xs)
    return X == Y
```

Comment: This requires a clarification about whether your interpretation or mine is what OP intends, but your code will return `True` for `X = [1, 2, 3, 1]` and `Y = [1, 2, 3]`; mine will return `False`. Yours also ignores the requirement for at least 2 elements (though there too I am not 100% sure if my interpretation is correct). However, I am certain OP can smash something together from our two solutions...

Comment: @Amadan The length two thing was unclear to me and trivially added, so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is correct solution:

```py
def check_order(X, Y):
    X = [x for x in X if x in Y]
    for i in range(len(X) - 1):
        if Y.index(X[i]) > Y.index(X[i + 1]):
            return False
    return True


def test_order():
    Y = ['a', 'b', 'd']

    X = ['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd']  # Returns True
    assert check_order(X, Y)

    X = ['a', 'b']  # Returns True
    assert check_order(X, Y)

    X = ['d', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b']  # Returns False
    assert not check_order(X, Y)

    X = ['c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']  # Returns True
    assert check_order(X, Y)
```